# disk I/O error with SQLite VACUUM

Tags: perl, sqlite, io, dbi

I got this problem with a SQLite DB I access through a Perl program.
I can use the INSERT and DELETE commands, but not VACUUM which raises an error : "disk I/O error".

If I run the program as root I got no problem so I guess it must be some permission issue. I checked permissions for every file involved in the process and it should be ok.
I really do not understand. Is the VACUUM command performing I/O operations outside the DB directory ?

Thanx in advance for your help.
Best regards,

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:someDB.db", undef, undef, {RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 1});
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("VACUUM;");
$sth->execute;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd like to see I/O operations which are executed during `VACUUM` you can use [strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace). It will list all system calls executed by SQLite, including disk IO.

```
strace sqlite3 someDB.db 'VACUUM;'
```